# Cucumber report for multiple stages in pipeline - only last one is shown

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cucumber, report

I've been using cucumber in my project + selenium(Java) tests. I decided to use Cucumber reports to read the nice reports and show them to the business. However, the reports do not meet my requirements, at least not in the config I have. What I have is several jobs (1) UK, 2) FR, 3) DE etc) and in each job I have steps in the pipeline that would contain many stages 1) Login Scenarios, 2) create user scenarios, 3) Add to cart scenarios etc

now, in the pipeline I have

```
stage('Login Scenarios') {
          steps {
              catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
             sh 'mvn -f pom.xml clean test --batch-mode -DbrowserStack="true" -Denvironment="preprod" -Dlanguage="uk" -Dbrowser="chrome" -DbrowserVersion="102" -Dos="Windows" -DosVersion="10" -Dcucumber.options="--tags @uk --tags @login"'
          }
          }
        }
    stage('Register User Scenarios') {
           steps {
               catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
             sh 'mvn -f pom.xml clean test --batch-mode -DbrowserStack="true" -Denvironment="preprod" -Dlanguage="uk" -Dbrowser="chrome" -DbrowserVersion="102" -Dos="Windows" -DosVersion="10" -Dcucumber.options="--tags @uk --tags @register"'
           } 
           }
        }
    stage('Add to Cart Scenarios') {
          steps {
              catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
             sh 'mvn -f pom.xml clean test --batch-mode -DbrowserStack="true" -Denvironment="preprod" -Dlanguage="uk" -Dbrowser="chrome" -DbrowserVersion="102" -Dos="Windows" -DosVersion="10" -Dcucumber.options="--tags @uk --tags @cart"'
          }
          }
        }

 post {
        always {
            cucumber buildStatus: 'UNSTABLE',
                jsonReportDirectory: 'target',
                fileIncludePattern: '**/reports/Cucumber.json'
            
        }
    }
```

TestRunner contains:

```
  plugin = {"pretty",
                "json:target/reports/Cucumber.json",
                "html:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.html",
                "junit:target/reports/Cucumber.xml"},
```

Issue is now that only last one (Cart Scenarios) are visible in the cucumber report. Do you know how to do it to have all the scenarios (stages) in the report? And how to configure it, or what is the best way (maybe different reporting tool?) to have it?

Comment: I think the problem is that `mvn clean` deletes the `target` directory and thus you only get the last report. But the solution propabely is not that easy -- I suspect even without the `clean` the reports lwill get overwritten. What plugin do you use for running the test, which for generating the reports?

Comment: for running tests I have surefire and for reporting I don't have any plugin declared in pom.xml, I only have cucumber.report.json.location and cucumber.report.location declared in pom's <properties> but I can switch to any other reporting tool to only have 1)nice reports and 2) reports visible for all features for all pipeline stages

Comment: What is your intention with running the Scenarios in dedicated calls? Would it be an option to run your tests all tests sequentially in surefire?

Comment: I don't know, I'd prefer pararell run, but for sake of good reports I can consider all options. Can you say something more? How to do it and how/what reports are from it?

Comment: Try checking https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html